# Placing an draggable image onto PDF in Android

Tags: android, pdf, drag-and-drop

Here is my problem:

I need to create an interface, where a user could see a low-quality version of a PDF page, and choose a place to drop a small image onto. After that, I need to get the page number and the coordinates of the top-left corner and the bottom-right corner. I also need to make sure, that there is no way to move the image outside of the PDF.

What I could come up on my own, was to somehow convert the PDF to a bunch of images, which I could then show, and change pages, by just loading the image for the next page. And I could then create some sort of draggable on top of that, and read the coordinates.

So could anyone tell me how to get this done?
As a bonus, could someone help me with some tutorials, links and the sort, to resources that could help me with this?

From where I stand, this could be VERY interesting, but also very resource intensive, since the PDF's should be converted on the fly. Can it be done page by page?

Some technical specs:

- Max file size - 4Mb, so the PDF wouldn't be awfully big
- Min API - 8. I need it to work on Android 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've tried this out, and it all comes grinding to a halt on the PDF to image conversion, which with Open-source libraries takes about 10s for each page, making this a Non-option. A hat tip to Adobe for making it so fast with their app.